# keep source documentation line breaks in doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I am looking for a global parameter that will tell doxygen HTML to keep line breaks in paragraphs as they are in the source. For example, my source documentation is:

```
/// \par Description.  
///      a description.  
///      a description.  
///      a description.
```

The documentation generated is:

```
Description.  
a description. a description. a description.
```

and I want the line breaks to be kept as in the source. I am using doxywizard so please tell me the section and the parameter.

Comment: Did you try with either <br> or \n at the end?

Comment: I tried but it does not work and I don't want to fill my code with tags that does not help to it's readability